# matlab function inputs from other .mat files?

Tags: matlab, functional-programming

I wrote a function and it requires some input values from other .mat files, I don't really know how to do this, can someone help please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `load` function is documented here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html

Answer (score 0):

Just load those .mat files in your function.